# NoMethodError in Author#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have no idea why it is showing me this problem NO Method in Author.
Showing /home/muba/muba/app/views/author/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

```
<%= form_for @author do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, class:'form-control' %><br/>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Author.rb Controller

```
class AuthorController < ApplicationController
def new
@page_title= 'Add new Author'
@author = Author.new
end

def create
end

def update
end

def edit
end

def destroy
end

def index
end

def show
end
def author_params 
params.require(:author).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
end
```

But Same Thing I did for my Categories page that is working. The code is:

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name, class:'form-control' %><br/>
</div>
<%=f.submit "Submit", class:'btn btn-primary' %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", categories_path, class:'btn btn-default' %> 
<% end %>
```

Category.rb controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def new
@page_title= 'Add new Category'
@category= Category.new
end

def create
end

def update
end

def edit
end

def destroy
end

def index
end

def show
end
def category_params 
params.require(:category).permit(:name)
end
end
```

Comment: Seeing your author model and schema.rb would be helpful.

Comment: Author model

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
end

Comment: Here is my Schema.rb
http://prntscr.com/971mfs

Comment: On side note, try following ruby style guide from [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: Open rails console and check if `Author.new.first_name` works.

Comment: It is working @Vasu Adari

Comment: Could you append the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed there is issue in your first line it should be

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
```

instead of

```
class AuthorController < ApplicationController
```

also make sure your controller's file name is **`authors_controller.rb`**

Ruby on Rails follow **linguistic convention**. Check **[Ruby and Rails Naming Conventions](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7)**

Comment: @J.M.MubasshirRahman : also change your `routes.rb` to http://pastebin.com/qhHcis5W

Answer (score 0):

In your view :

```
<%= form_for @author do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, class:'form-control' %><br/>
</div>

<% end %>
```

here , make sure the `first_name` is present as a column name in your Author model in the table in the database . It will check the exact name in the table which will raise an error if the name doesn't match .

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please see this... I have first_name in author model and also in table in Database

Comment: Author Model

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
end

Comment: @J.M.MubasshirRahman :  can you show your `routes.rb` please ?

Comment: you don't need those first  extra `gets` as adding `resources :abc` does the work for you . so please remove the gets which are in `REST` methods and then try . It should work .